# display new data in a text area with a line break

Tags: php, zend-framework, textarea

```
<textarea name="notes"rows="2" cols="70" readonly><?php if(!empty($this->log_note)){ echo $this->log_note;} ?>
</textarea><br><br> 
<label for="add_note"> Add Note </label>
<textarea name="add_note" rows="2" cols="70">
</textarea>
```

Lets say I have a text area in a form that displays data from a database table.

Now I have another text area field, and when I enter data it will update the above table field with the data entered.

```
    $post_notes=$this->post['notes'];
    $post_add_note=$post_notes."<br>".$this->post['add_note'];

    $add_note_update=$this->db->query("
                     UPDATE notes SET note='$post_add_note' WHERE id='$hidden_id'
                 ");
```

Now next time when I display the text area field with the name 'notes', I want the data in the text area to be displayed in a newline. i.e My 
 tag should work or is there any other way to display it with a line break?

NOTE: I will take care of the SQL injection scenarios, but I want to get my logic right first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any line breaks in the space between the `<textarea></textarea>` tags are displayed in the text box. If you replace `"<br>"` with `"\n"` it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Best way when u typing your data in textarea please add at the end of line "< br  />"
It will start printing next data in new line.

eg:
abc< br />
xyz< br />

output look like:
abc
xyz